# Change article Status based on Workflow module

Tags: workflows

I have Workflow set up properly. But when an article is created, it is set to Published automatically. It doesn't appear to the public though, unless the Workflow status is set to Live.

Is there a way to customize the status to be more specific (e.g. say "Pending Review" when the workflow is in Review status, then say "Published" when workflow is in Live)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, install the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

I would highly recommend watching the [Rules video series at NodeOne](http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework) by the incredibly talented Johan Falk.

With the Workflow module and the Rules module installed and configured we can create a rule that automatically publishes (or unpublished) content based on it's current workflow state.

To ensure our content is not published by default, we will need to change a few things.  Visit example.com/admin/structure/types (if clean URL's are enabled) and click edit next to the content type you're working with. Scroll to the "publishing options" and uncheck "Published" so new content is not publicly visible by default.

---

[image: Uncheck published box]

---

Next, create a new rule.  Available at example.com/admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add once the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module is installed and enabled.

Configure your new rule to react on the event: "Workflow State Has Changed" and click save.

---

[image: react on workflow change]

---

Next, add a new condition.

---

[image: add condition]

---

Choose the "Check workflow transition" condition.

---

[image: check workflow transition]

---

Configure which transition you wish to react on.  For example, if you have created the workflow states "Pending Approval" and "Published" you would choose "Pending Approval" under "Old Workflow State" and "Published" under new workflow state.

---

[image: configure states to check against]

---

Now we can automatically trigger actions once Rules detects a workflow transition from "Pending approval" to "Published".  For example, we can trigger an email to editors, publish a node or just about anything else.

Next we need to add an action.

---

[image: add an action]

---

There are dozens of built in actions, and you can even add your own.  One that you may specifically be looking for though is "Publish content."

---

[image: list of actions]

---

Rules and Workflow work very well together in this sense and will likely be able to do everything you need.

I hope this helps. If I misunderstood your question or if I got too off topic I'll try again. :)

Comment: This sounds like what I want. :) I will give it a try and see if it works the way I intended and let you know if it doesn't. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Citricguy, this works *almost* how I want. The thing that'd I'd like to do that is different is in the Add Action item. When workflow has changed from Creation to Pending Approval, I want the Action to change the Status (on the Content Overview page) from Unpublished to Pending Approval. Is that possible?

Comment: Which content overview page? admin/content?  Or is this a Workflow (Module) state transition?

Comment: The admin/content page that lists all the pages (published or unpublished). URL will be something like: www.domain.com/admin/content

Comment: Without a doubt the module you're looking for is http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/  Use this with the Rules module (create a Rules component) for best results. :)

Comment: Great answer @Citricguy.I got what I needed from that in 2 minutes (whereas it would have taken me longer than that to FIND what I needed in a video)... thanks for taking the time and not just handing it off to a link.